# mongodb multiple key aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a sql background and understand the syntax for aggregating data in mongodb, but I'm having trouble with "flattening" the output of a multiple key aggregation in MongoDB.  For example, the standard syntax is the following:

```
db.transactions.aggregate(
    [
     { $group: { _id: {"category":"$category","postdate":"$postdate"} , "total": { $sum: "$total" } } }
    ]
);
```

But this returns the data in the following form:

```
[{"_id":{"category":"Fees","postdate":"2013-01-04T05:00:00.000Z"},"total":24},
{"_id":{"category":"Fees","postdate":"2012-12-20T05:00:00.000Z"},"total":-0.02}]
```

What I want is the data in a format like the following where I'm still grouping on two or more columns:

Option 1:

```
[{"_id":"Auto","postdate":"2013-01-04T05:00:00.000Z","total":24},
{"_id":"Fees","postdate":"2012-12-20T05:00:00.000Z","total":-0.02}]
```

Option 2:

```
["category":"Auto","postdate":"2013-01-04T05:00:00.000Z","total":24},
{"category":"Fees","postdate":"2012-12-20T05:00:00.000Z","total":-0.02}]
```

How do I do this in mongodb?

Comment: The option 1 first row should be 'Fees'. Is that a typo ?

Comment: No the second should actually be 'Auto'. Changed it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand that. Are you expecting just the category to change ? Can you include  sample docs ? You are grouping by category followed by post date in the aggregation. You'll need one more group stage to group them by category.

Comment: Your response below answers the question.  It was just a typo.  I have different values for category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Format your response using ***[$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)***

Option 1:

```
db.transactions.aggregate(
        [
         { $group: { _id: {"category":"$category","postdate":"$postdate"} , "total": { $sum: "$total" } } },
         { $project: { "_id":0, "_id":"$_id.category", "postdate":"$_id.postdate", "total":1 } }
        ]
);
```

Option 2:

```
db.transactions.aggregate(
        [
         { $group: { _id: {"category":"$category","postdate":"$postdate"} , "total": { $sum: "$total" } } },
         { $project: { "_id":0, "category":"$_id.category", "postdate":"$_id.postdate", "total":1 } }
        ]
);
```